# material-ui 4.3.2 context menu mouse right click position

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using material-ui 4.3.2 menu with popper. I need to display the menu dynamically positioned. I just modify a sample codesandbox from material-ui. In this sample, menu appears when you select some text. But not positioned. Menu needs to be anchored with an actual DOM element I guess.
How can I make it?

Thanks & regards

```
import React from "react";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

export default function FakedReferencePopper() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | any>(null);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();

    // Resets when the selection has a length of 0
    if (!selection || selection.anchorOffset === selection.focusOffset) {
      handleClose();
      return;
    }

    const getBoundingClientRect = () =>
      selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();

    setOpen(true);
    setAnchorEl({
      clientWidth: getBoundingClientRect().width,
      clientHeight: getBoundingClientRect().height,
      getBoundingClientRect
    });
  };

  const id = open ? "faked-reference-popper" : undefined;

  return (
    <div onMouseLeave={handleClose}>
      <Typography aria-describedby={id} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ipsum
        purus, bibendum sit amet vulputate eget, porta semper ligula. Donec
        bibendum vulputate erat, ac fringilla mi finibus nec. Donec ac dolor sed
        dolor porttitor blandit vel vel purus. Fusce vel malesuada ligula. Nam
        quis vehicula ante, eu finibus est. Proin ullamcorper fermentum orci,
        quis finibus massa. Nunc lobortis, massa ut rutrum ultrices, metus metus
        finibus ex, sit amet facilisis neque enim sed neque. Quisque accumsan
        metus vel maximus consequat. Suspendisse lacinia tellus a libero
        volutpat maximus.
      </Typography>
      <Popper
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        transition
        placement="bottom-start"
      >
        {({ TransitionProps }) => (
          <Menu
            id="simple-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        )}
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-82lj2

Answer (score 1):

`Menu` internally uses [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/) which is similar to `Popper` but is based on the `Modal` component. `Popover's` positioning mechanism is similar to `Popper`, but not the same. In order to do a menu within `Popper`, you should look at the [MenuList composition demo](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#menulist-composition).

Instead of using `Menu`, you can use `MenuList` wrapped by a `Paper` component.

```
          <Paper className={menuClasses.paper}>
            <MenuList className={menuClasses.list} autoFocus>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </MenuList>
          </Paper>
```

The two CSS classes (`paper` and `list`) are copied from `Menu`.

Here's the full code:

```
import React from "react";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import MenuList from "@material-ui/core/MenuList";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

/* copied from https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.3.2/packages/material-ui/src/Menu/Menu.js#L21 */
const useMenuStyles = makeStyles({
  /* Styles applied to the `Paper` component. */
  paper: {
    // specZ: The maximum height of a simple menu should be one or more rows less than the view
    // height. This ensures a tapable area outside of the simple menu with which to dismiss
    // the menu.
    maxHeight: "calc(100% - 96px)",
    // Add iOS momentum scrolling.
    WebkitOverflowScrolling: "touch"
  },
  /* Styles applied to the `List` component via `MenuList`. */
  list: {
    // We disable the focus ring for mouse, touch and keyboard users.
    outline: 0
  }
});

export default function FakedReferencePopper() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | any>(null);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();

    // Resets when the selection has a length of 0
    if (!selection || selection.anchorOffset === selection.focusOffset) {
      handleClose();
      return;
    }

    const getBoundingClientRect = () =>
      selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();

    setOpen(true);
    setAnchorEl({
      clientWidth: getBoundingClientRect().width,
      clientHeight: getBoundingClientRect().height,
      getBoundingClientRect
    });
  };

  const id = open ? "faked-reference-popper" : undefined;
  const menuClasses = useMenuStyles();
  return (
    <div onMouseLeave={handleClose}>
      <Typography aria-describedby={id} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ipsum
        purus, bibendum sit amet vulputate eget, porta semper ligula. Donec
        bibendum vulputate erat, ac fringilla mi finibus nec. Donec ac dolor sed
        dolor porttitor blandit vel vel purus. Fusce vel malesuada ligula. Nam
        quis vehicula ante, eu finibus est. Proin ullamcorper fermentum orci,
        quis finibus massa. Nunc lobortis, massa ut rutrum ultrices, metus metus
        finibus ex, sit amet facilisis neque enim sed neque. Quisque accumsan
        metus vel maximus consequat. Suspendisse lacinia tellus a libero
        volutpat maximus.
      </Typography>
      <Popper
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        transition
        placement="bottom-start"
      >
        {({ TransitionProps }) => (
          <Paper className={menuClasses.paper}>
            <MenuList className={menuClasses.list} autoFocus>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </MenuList>
          </Paper>
        )}
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Context menu]